# Eisenstein series associated with the cusps of a congruence subgroup

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

While reading a paper I came across the phrase "the Eisenstein series of weight 2 associated with the cusps of $\Gamma_{0}(6)$". Can anyone give me the definition of Eisenstein series of weight $k$ associated with the cusps of $\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is a congruence subgroup of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Dear Shayla, How much do you know about modular forms and modular curves?  (The answer to this will be very helpful in formulating an answer to your question.)  Regards,

Comment: Aside from the basic definitions related to modular forms, not very much.

Answer (score 8):

In general, for congruence subgroups $\Gamma$ of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, the collection of weight $k$ Eisenstein series is spanned by functions formed by 
$$ E(z)=E(z,c_o,d_o,N,k)=\sum''_{c=c_o,d=d_o(N)}\;\;\frac{1}{(cz+d)^k}$$
where $c,d$ run over _relatively_prime_ integers congruence to $c_o,d_o$ mod $N$. Especially for composite $N$, there are (elementary) relations among these. Eisenstein series are far more elementary objects than most other modular forms.

However, those sums only converge absolutely for $k>2$. Many decades ago, E. Hecke had already addressed this "problem", by what is now called "Hecke summation" (although it can be understood more systematically, too): throw in a "summation factor" to make the series converge when $k=2$:
$$ E(z,s) = \sum''_{c=c_o,d=d_o(N)}\;\frac{1}{|cz+d|^{2s}\cdot (cz+d)^2}$$
with $\Re(s)>0$. The *plan* is to analytically continue in $s$ to a neighborhood of $s=0$, and then set $s=0$.

The latter plan does largely succeed, *except* that it does not *always* produce holomorphic modular forms at $s=0$. This "disappointment" already occurs for $\Gamma=SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, where there is an extra summand of $1/y$ as part of the $0$th Fourier coefficient of the Hecke-summed Eisenstein series.

For Hilbert modular forms, that is, the analogue of elliptic modular forms but over larger (totally real) number fields in place of $\mathbb Q$, the "disappointment" never occurs. Although the computation to see the outcome is essentially elementary, the *reason* for it is not so elementary.

Comment: Could you share some more details on the Hecke summation? It's not clear to me how to decide if an analytic continuation exists.

Comment: @RidderJan, the computation is not so short... but/and if (in conformity with MSE conventions) pose that as a separate question, I will write something in the near future. My old book (c. 1990) on Holomorphic Hilbert Modular Forms does such computations in detail.